# How to hide custom TestCafe t.report data from spec output

Tags: testcafe

I want to use `t.report()` to pass lots of custom data to my custom reporter. However, all `t.report()` calls get logged to the default spec reporter output:

```
 Report data:
  - [object Object]
  - [object Object]
```

Is there any way to remove this output from the spec reporter logs? It is creating massive console logs of unnecessary data.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to remove this output from the **spec** reporter logs. The t.report method helps users avoid custom reporters and it is part of the spec reporter.
Please refer to the following topic to learn more: [t.report method](https://testcafe.io/documentation/404350/reference/test-api/testcontroller/report)

You can use `onBeforeWriteHook` to modify spec reporter output. Please refer to the following help topic for more info: [Modify Reporter Output](https://testcafe.io/documentation/404388/guides/advanced-guides/modify-reporter-output)

Comment: Ah great suggestion, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Added `onBeforeWrite` hook per previous suggestion. This worked perfectly to remove custom `t.report()` data from console / spec output.

```
    module.exports = {
        reporter: {
          onBeforeWrite: {
            spec: writeInfo => {
              if (writeInfo.initiator == "reportTestDone") {
                // Do not log custom t.report data to console
                writeInfo.data.testRunInfo.reportData = {};
              }
            },
          },
        },
      },
    };
```